# cakephp different layouts have different error messages for the same error

Tags: cakephp, layout, error-handling, themes

In the default layout you get an error message for a missing controller (which is right because the controller doesn't exist)

But when I switch to a different layout I just get: `an internal error has occurred`. What causes this, and how can I make sure to get the default error messages in my custom layout?

I use cakephp 2.3.5 and switch using this setting in the BeforeRenderer of AppController.php:

```
$this->layout = 'admin';
```

The only thing I changed is uncomment/comment is this line. I tested the problem with a copy of the default layout in the admin theme and still the error message is diffrent.

Error message with custom layout:

> Controller class GroupsController could not be found. Error: An
>   Internal Error Has Occurred.
>
> Stack Trace APP/webroot/index.php line 109 →
>   Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)

Error message with default layout:

> Missing Controller Error: GroupsController could not be found.
>
> Error: Create the class GroupsController below in file:
>   app/Controller/GroupsController.php
>
> ```
> ?php class GroupsController extends AppController {
> }
> ```
>
> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create
>   app/View/Errors/missing_controller.ctp
>
> Stack Trace APP/webroot/index.php line 109 →
>   Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)

Comment: Seems weird, layout change isn't related to exception handling... Couldn't it be that your custom layout has an error? Or that beforeRender in AppController has an error? Do you have debug set to > 2 ? Maybe it helps a bit to know what the problem is.

Comment: Debug is set to 2. It seems the same error, just a different text message (as if debug isn't set to 2 anymore). I'll modify my question and add the error text and layout code

Comment: It appears my custom layout isn't the problem, I copied the default layout and still the error messages are different

Answer (score 0):

As in [CakePHP Docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/errors.html), you can create a customized AppError to handle any kind of errors, 404 not found, controller/component/helper not found, Security Errors...

I did a method, in my AppController, that checks if the view name is an error.

You can use:

```
if ( $this->name == 'CakeError' ) {
    $this->layout = 'cake';
    return;
}
```

See lib\Cake\View\Errors for available views for errors, if you are curious.

Comment: The problem is I don't want a  customised error message, the problem is I get a different error message when I switch the layout. And I expect the same message